# Saving files via the "Save to Drive" JS widget is not working

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to implement the ["Save to Drive"](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/savetodrive) widget, available from the Google Drive API.

The widget button appears on the page, I can click the button to open the [popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NWQ5.png), but when I click save within the window, nothing is happening.

I am using the following html code within my page, which is nearly identical the the demo from the API:

```
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <div style="width:200px;height:200px" >
        <div class="g-savetodrive"
           data-src="https://path/to/my/file"
           data-filename="My Statement.pdf"
           data-sitename="My Company Name">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have checked the file I am saving is on the same domain and can be accessed via the URL directly.

I am using the Google Chrome browser, I do not see any errors in the network or JS console, whilst saving.
Within the popup window, I am able to change drive folder and google account to use, so the window is functional.

I have seen a JS error within the popup window which occurs when it opens, not sure if it is relevant:

```
Uncaught TypeError: gapi.loaded_0 is not a function
    at cb=gapi.loaded_0:1
```

I have no idea why the save is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @alberto vielma - I have updated my question. Due to the nature of the issue, I do not know how else to improve it.

Comment: Are you using any extra Google code? Because the error you are receiving about ```gapi``` could be related to [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js)

Comment: The Google tag manager libraries are the only additional code, no other Google Drive specific code is being used.

Also I have tested using a page with only the API HTML, and experience the same issue, nothing happens when I click save.

Comment: I am using [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/savetodrive), which should not require API authentication setup. The widget allows users to save to their own drive, so long as they are signed into their google account.

Comment: I am trying to get the same behaviour than you're getting, but for it's working normally. I would recommend you contact [G Suite support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Unfortunately as I am not a G Suite Admin user, I cannot submit a support request, which led me to this forum.


When you say it is working normally for you, are you testing with a simple HTML page containing only the code I have demonstrated? Also, if you define an invalid filename, do you receive any error? I am not seeing any at all.